# Using jQuery .empty() to remove dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, dynamic, append, simplyscroll

I'm using the jQuery [SimplyScroll plugin](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/) to create a circular image carousel on my page. I start off with a simple empty `<div>`:

```
<div id="scroller-wrapper">

</div>
```

I then append an unordered list...

```
$("#scroller-wrapper").append("<ul id='scroller' />");
```

...to which I dynamically add the images and then initiate the SimplyScroll plugin. That results in this:

```
<div id="scroller-wrapper">
    <div class="simply-scroll simply-scroll-container">
        <div class="simply-scroll-clip">
            <ul id="scroller" class="simply-scroll-list" style="width: 2808px;">
                <li><img src="image1.png" alt="Image 1" /></li>
                <!-- more images -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far so good. The problem is that periodically, I need to completely empty the scroller and reinitialize it with all new images. So at the time the unordered list is appended, I tried emptying the wrapping `<div>` first, like this:

```
$("#scroller-wrapper").empty().append("<ul id='scroller' />");
```

But as you can see, SimplyScroll has dynamically inserted a few of its own `<div>`s, and those don't seem to be affected by `.empty()`. So when I reinitialize the scroller, I get this:

```
<div id="scroller-wrapper">
    <div class="simply-scroll simply-scroll-container">
        <div class="simply-scroll-clip">
            <div class="simply-scroll simply-scroll-container">
                <div class="simply-scroll-clip">
                    <ul id="scroller" class="simply-scroll-list" style="width: 2808px;">
                        <li><img src="image1.png" alt="Image 1" /></li>
                        <!-- more images -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since the `<div>`s that were generated by SimplyScroll weren't removed, the new scroller is appended inside of them and it doesn't work.

How do I completely empty out the contents of `#scroller`, including the dynamically added elements, so that I can start over "from scratch" each time I initialize the scroller?

Comment: Try `$("#scroller").text('');`

Comment: Reapplying a plugin to an element successfully depends on how the plugin was written. In this case it is not designed to be reapplied. You need to either restore the HTML to your original (by removing the entire parent with `remove()`) or see if you can get SimplyScroll to accept updates to items within it.

Comment: `empty()` probably is working, I have to think that your first SimplyScroll is still running (off timers) and simply adds back the missing elements when it sees them missing. Your second SimplyScroll probably adds the second lot around your target `#scroller`. What you need to find out is how to shutdown a SimplyScroll completely.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: removing the parent `<div>` with `.remove()` and then regenerating the HTML from scratch fixed the nesting issue – thanks! But it still doesn't work: SimplyScroll doesn't assign a width to `<div id="scroller">` the second time. You're probably right that the first instance is still running. Any ideas how I can remove that completely?

Comment: Someone asked a similar question [here](https://github.com/logicbox/jquery-simplyscroll/issues/8) 6 months ago, with no response...

Comment: Hm...I tried applying a unique ID to every scroller that gets generated, but still, only the first one works...can you not have multiple instances running concurrently?

Comment: Looking through the source for SimplyScroll.js it does not appear to remember the class instances on the `data()` of the elements (which you normally do with addins). There appears to be no way to get at the instances once run and they only do one-shot runs (can't change options, or call methods once running). I would suggest tweaking their source to store the class instance in the elements `data()` so you can call a new method to shut them down. Basically SimplyScroll appears to be *a cheap and cheerful* add-in, not designed for anything non-standard or non-static.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38119/discussion-between-daguy-and-trueblueaussie)

Comment: Was it resolved? Stuck at same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have ported some standard code I use from TypeScript to Javascript and enhanced SimplyScroll to support instance data and method calls.

I also added `stop` and `start` methods for you to allow you to kill the timers and reinitialise the layout after items change.

I don't have time to complete this, but it should give you the hooks you need now.

Use it like this:

```
$("#images").simplyScroll({...options...});
```

Then when you want to change content:

```
$('#images').simplyScroll('stop');
$('#images').empty().append('...new content...')
$('#images').simplyScroll('start');
```

Full modified code below:

```
/*
 * simplyScroll 2 - a scroll-tastic jQuery plugin
 *
 * http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009-2012 Will Kelly - http://logicbox.net
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 *
 * Version: 2.0.5 Last revised: 10/05/2012
 *
 */

(function ($, window, undefined) {
    $.fn.simplyScroll = function (options, args) {
        var THIS = this;
        // If a string is supplied, assume we are calling a method on the add-in
        if (typeof options === 'string') {
            this.each(function () {
                var instance = $(this).data('simplyscroll');
                if (!instance) {
                    alert("Attempted to call method '" + options + "' prior to initialization.");
                    return;
                }
                if (!$.isFunction(instance[options])) {
                    alert("Method '" + options + "' does not exist");
                    return;
                }
                instance[options].apply(instance, args);
            });

        }
        else {
            THIS.each(function () {
                var instance = $(this).data('simplyscroll');
                if (instance) {
                    // Reinit the add-in options
                    instance._changeOptions(options);
                } else {
                    $(this).data('simplyscroll', new $.simplyScroll(this, options));
                }
            });
        }
        return THIS;
        //return this.each(function () {
        //    new $.simplyScroll(this, options);
        //});
    };

    var defaults = {
        customClass: 'simply-scroll',
        frameRate: 24, //No of movements per second
        speed: 1, //No of pixels per frame
        orientation: 'horizontal', //'horizontal or 'vertical' - not to be confused with device orientation
        auto: true,
        autoMode: 'loop', //auto = true, 'loop' or 'bounce',
        manualMode: 'end', //auto = false, 'loop' or 'end'
        direction: 'forwards', //'forwards' or 'backwards'.
        pauseOnHover: true, //autoMode = loop|bounce only
        pauseOnTouch: true, //" touch device only
        pauseButton: false, //" generates an extra element to allow manual pausing 
        startOnLoad: false //use this to delay starting of plugin until all page assets have loaded
    };

    $.simplyScroll = function (el, options) {

        var self = this;

        this.o = $.extend({}, defaults, options || {});
        this.isAuto = this.o.auto !== false && this.o.autoMode.match(/^loop|bounce$/) !== null;
        this.isHorizontal = this.o.orientation.match(/^horizontal|vertical$/) !== null && this.o.orientation == defaults.orientation;
        this.isRTL = this.isHorizontal && $("html").attr('dir') == 'rtl';
        this.isForwards = !this.isAuto || (this.isAuto && this.o.direction.match(/^forwards|backwards$/) !== null && this.o.direction == defaults.direction) && !this.isRTL;
        this.isLoop = this.isAuto && this.o.autoMode == 'loop' || !this.isAuto && this.o.manualMode == 'loop';

        this.supportsTouch = ('createTouch' in document);

        this.events = this.supportsTouch ?
        { start: 'touchstart MozTouchDown', move: 'touchmove MozTouchMove', end: 'touchend touchcancel MozTouchRelease' } :
        { start: 'mouseenter', end: 'mouseleave' };

        this.$list = $(el); //called on ul/ol/div etc
        var $items = this.$list.children();

        //generate extra markup
        this.$list.addClass('simply-scroll-list')
            .wrap('<div class="simply-scroll-clip"></div>')
            .parent().wrap('<div class="' + this.o.customClass + ' simply-scroll-container"></div>');

        if (!this.isAuto) { //button placeholders
            this.$list.parent().parent()
            .prepend('<div class="simply-scroll-forward"></div>')
            .prepend('<div class="simply-scroll-back"></div>');
        } else {
            if (this.o.pauseButton) {
                this.$list.parent().parent()
                .prepend('<div class="simply-scroll-btn simply-scroll-btn-pause"></div>');
                this.o.pauseOnHover = false;
            }
        }

        //wrap an extra div around the whole lot if elements scrolled aren't equal
        if ($items.length > 1) {

            var extra_wrap = false,
                total = 0;

            if (this.isHorizontal) {
                $items.each(function () { total += $(this).outerWidth(true); });
                extra_wrap = $items.eq(0).outerWidth(true) * $items.length !== total;
            } else {
                $items.each(function () { total += $(this).outerHeight(true); });
                extra_wrap = $items.eq(0).outerHeight(true) * $items.length !== total;
            }

            if (extra_wrap) {
                this.$list = this.$list.wrap('<div></div>').parent().addClass('simply-scroll-list');
                if (this.isHorizontal) {
                    this.$list.children().css({ "float": 'left', width: total + 'px' });
                } else {
                    this.$list.children().css({ height: total + 'px' });
                }
            }
        }

        if (!this.o.startOnLoad) {
            this.init();
        } else {
            //wait for load before completing setup
            $(window).load(function () { self.init(); });
        }

    };

    $.simplyScroll.fn = $.simplyScroll.prototype = {};

    $.simplyScroll.fn.extend = $.simplyScroll.extend = $.extend;

    $.simplyScroll.fn.extend({
        _changeOptions: function (options) {
            // Options have changed - reinit
        },
        stop: function () {
            this.isAuto = false;
            this.moveStop(this.movement);
        },
        start: function () {
            this.init();
            this.isAuto = true;
        },
        init: function () {

            this.$items = this.$list.children();
            this.$clip = this.$list.parent(); //this is the element that scrolls
            this.$container = this.$clip.parent();
            this.$btnBack = $('.simply-scroll-back', this.$container);
            this.$btnForward = $('.simply-scroll-forward', this.$container);


            if (!this.isHorizontal) {
                this.itemMax = this.$items.eq(0).outerHeight(true);
                this.clipMax = this.$clip.height();
                this.dimension = 'height';
                this.moveBackClass = 'simply-scroll-btn-up';
                this.moveForwardClass = 'simply-scroll-btn-down';
                this.scrollPos = 'Top';
            } else {
                this.itemMax = this.$items.eq(0).outerWidth(true);
                this.clipMax = this.$clip.width();
                this.dimension = 'width';
                this.moveBackClass = 'simply-scroll-btn-left';
                this.moveForwardClass = 'simply-scroll-btn-right';
                this.scrollPos = 'Left';
            }

            this.posMin = 0;

            this.posMax = this.$items.length * this.itemMax;

            var addItems = Math.ceil(this.clipMax / this.itemMax);

            //auto scroll loop & manual scroll bounce or end(to-end)
            if (this.isAuto && this.o.autoMode == 'loop') {

                this.$list.css(this.dimension, this.posMax + (this.itemMax * addItems) + 'px');

                this.posMax += (this.clipMax - this.o.speed);

                if (this.isForwards) {
                    this.$items.slice(0, addItems).clone(true).appendTo(this.$list);
                    this.resetPosition = 0;

                } else {
                    this.$items.slice(-addItems).clone(true).prependTo(this.$list);
                    this.resetPosition = this.$items.length * this.itemMax;
                    //due to inconsistent RTL implementation force back to LTR then fake
                    if (this.isRTL) {
                        this.$clip[0].dir = 'ltr';
                        //based on feedback seems a good idea to force float right
                        this.$items.css('float', 'right');
                    }
                }

                //manual and loop
            } else if (!this.isAuto && this.o.manualMode == 'loop') {

                this.posMax += this.itemMax * addItems;

                this.$list.css(this.dimension, this.posMax + (this.itemMax * addItems) + 'px');

                this.posMax += (this.clipMax - this.o.speed);

                var items_append = this.$items.slice(0, addItems).clone(true).appendTo(this.$list);
                var items_prepend = this.$items.slice(-addItems).clone(true).prependTo(this.$list);

                this.resetPositionForwards = this.resetPosition = addItems * this.itemMax;
                this.resetPositionBackwards = this.$items.length * this.itemMax;

                //extra events to force scroll direction change
                var self = this;

                this.$btnBack.bind(this.events.start, function () {
                    self.isForwards = false;
                    self.resetPosition = self.resetPositionBackwards;
                });

                this.$btnForward.bind(this.events.start, function () {
                    self.isForwards = true;
                    self.resetPosition = self.resetPositionForwards;
                });

            } else { //(!this.isAuto && this.o.manualMode=='end') 

                this.$list.css(this.dimension, this.posMax + 'px');

                if (this.isForwards) {
                    this.resetPosition = 0;

                } else {
                    this.resetPosition = this.$items.length * this.itemMax;
                    //due to inconsistent RTL implementation force back to LTR then fake
                    if (this.isRTL) {
                        this.$clip[0].dir = 'ltr';
                        //based on feedback seems a good idea to force float right
                        this.$items.css('float', 'right');
                    }
                }
            }

            this.resetPos() //ensure scroll position is reset

            this.interval = null;
            this.intervalDelay = Math.floor(1000 / this.o.frameRate);

            if (!(!this.isAuto && this.o.manualMode == 'end')) { //loop mode
                //ensure that speed is divisible by item width. Helps to always make images even not odd widths!
                while (this.itemMax % this.o.speed !== 0) {
                    this.o.speed--;
                    if (this.o.speed === 0) {
                        this.o.speed = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            var self = this;
            this.trigger = null;
            this.funcMoveBack = function (e) {
                if (e !== undefined) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                self.trigger = !self.isAuto && self.o.manualMode == 'end' ? this : null;
                if (self.isAuto) {
                    self.isForwards ? self.moveBack() : self.moveForward();
                } else {
                    self.moveBack();
                }
            };
            this.funcMoveForward = function (e) {
                if (e !== undefined) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                self.trigger = !self.isAuto && self.o.manualMode == 'end' ? this : null;
                if (self.isAuto) {
                    self.isForwards ? self.moveForward() : self.moveBack();
                } else {
                    self.moveForward();
                }
            };
            this.funcMovePause = function () { self.movePause(); };
            this.funcMoveStop = function () { self.moveStop(); };
            this.funcMoveResume = function () { self.moveResume(); };

            if (this.isAuto) {

                this.paused = false;

                function togglePause() {
                    if (self.paused === false) {
                        self.paused = true;
                        self.funcMovePause();
                    } else {
                        self.paused = false;
                        self.funcMoveResume();
                    }
                    return self.paused;
                };

                //disable pauseTouch when links are present
                if (this.supportsTouch && this.$items.find('a').length) {
                    this.supportsTouch = false;
                }

                if (this.isAuto && this.o.pauseOnHover && !this.supportsTouch) {
                    this.$clip.bind(this.events.start, this.funcMovePause).bind(this.events.end, this.funcMoveResume);
                } else if (this.isAuto && this.o.pauseOnTouch && !this.o.pauseButton && this.supportsTouch) {

                    var touchStartPos, scrollStartPos;

                    this.$clip.bind(this.events.start, function (e) {
                        togglePause();
                        var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
                        touchStartPos = self.isHorizontal ? touch.pageX : touch.pageY;
                        scrollStartPos = self.$clip[0]['scroll' + self.scrollPos];
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        e.preventDefault();

                    }).bind(this.events.move, function (e) {

                        e.stopPropagation();
                        e.preventDefault();

                        var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0],
                            endTouchPos = self.isHorizontal ? touch.pageX : touch.pageY,
                            pos = (touchStartPos - endTouchPos) + scrollStartPos;

                        if (pos < 0) pos = 0;
                        else if (pos > self.posMax) pos = self.posMax;

                        self.$clip[0]['scroll' + self.scrollPos] = pos;

                        //force pause
                        self.funcMovePause();
                        self.paused = true;
                    });
                } else {
                    if (this.o.pauseButton) {

                        this.$btnPause = $(".simply-scroll-btn-pause", this.$container)
                            .bind('click', function (e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                togglePause() ? $(this).addClass('active') : $(this).removeClass('active');
                            });
                    }
                }
                this.funcMoveForward();
            } else {

                this.$btnBack
                    .addClass('simply-scroll-btn' + ' ' + this.moveBackClass)
                    .bind(this.events.start, this.funcMoveBack).bind(this.events.end, this.funcMoveStop);
                this.$btnForward
                    .addClass('simply-scroll-btn' + ' ' + this.moveForwardClass)
                    .bind(this.events.start, this.funcMoveForward).bind(this.events.end, this.funcMoveStop);

                if (this.o.manualMode == 'end') {
                    !this.isRTL ? this.$btnBack.addClass('disabled') : this.$btnForward.addClass('disabled');
                }
            }
        },
        moveForward: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.movement = 'forward';
            if (this.trigger !== null) {
                this.$btnBack.removeClass('disabled');
            }
            self.interval = setInterval(function () {
                if (self.$clip[0]['scroll' + self.scrollPos] < (self.posMax - self.clipMax)) {
                    self.$clip[0]['scroll' + self.scrollPos] += self.o.speed;
                } else if (self.isLoop) {
                    self.resetPos();
                } else {
                    self.moveStop(self.movement);
                }
            }, self.intervalDelay);
        },
        moveBack: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.movement = 'back';
            if (this.trigger !== null) {
                this.$btnForward.removeClass('disabled');
            }
            self.interval = setInterval(function () {
                if (self.$clip[0]['scroll' + self.scrollPos] > self.posMin) {
                    self.$clip[0]['scroll' + self.scrollPos] -= self.o.speed;
                } else if (self.isLoop) {
                    self.resetPos();
                } else {
                    self.moveStop(self.movement);
                }
            }, self.intervalDelay);
        },
        movePause: function () {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
        },
        moveStop: function (moveDir) {
            this.movePause();
            if (this.trigger !== null) {
                if (typeof moveDir !== 'undefined') {
                    $(this.trigger).addClass('disabled');
                }
                this.trigger = null;
            }
            if (this.isAuto) {
                if (this.o.autoMode == 'bounce') {
                    moveDir == 'forward' ? this.moveBack() : this.moveForward();
                }
            }
        },
        moveResume: function () {
            this.movement == 'forward' ? this.moveForward() : this.moveBack();
        },
        resetPos: function () {
            this.$clip[0]['scroll' + this.scrollPos] = this.resetPosition;
        }
    });

})(jQuery, window);
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can check if the scroller has been initialized? Something like `if (scroller.simplyScroll("init") == true) { ... }`? I have this working almost perfectly...

Comment: Do you mean from inside the addin, or outside in your JS code?

Comment: In my code – I want to check if the scroller is initialized already before I tell it to start.

Comment: You can check for `$(element).data('simplyscroll')`... that's where I store the instance. The moment you first called .simplyScroll though init is being called (during construction).

Comment: Can this be adapted to expose the '$items' somehow so that re-initialization is not needed? allowing for a truly dynamic scroller?